# How to insert a new element in between all elements of a Ruby array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an Array and want to insert a new element in between all elements, someway like the `join` method. For example, I have

```
[1, [], "333"]
```

and what I need is

```
[1, {}, [], {}, "333"]
```

Note a new empty hash was inserted in between all elements.

Edit:
Currently what I have is:

```
irb(main):028:0> a = [1, [], "333"]
=> [1, [], "333"]
irb(main):029:0> a = a.inject([]){|x, y| x << y; x << {}; x}
=> [1, {}, [], {}, "333", {}]
irb(main):030:0> a.pop
=> {}
irb(main):031:0> a
=> [1, {}, [], {}, "333"]
irb(main):032:0>
```

I want to know the best way.

Comment: `x.push(y, {})` is shorter, both `<<` and `push` return array, so you don't need `;x`, `inject` is slow

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
[1, 2, 3].flat_map { |x| [x, :a] }[0...-1]
#=> [1, :a, 2, :a, 3]
```

FYI, that function is called [intersperse](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputlist/intersperse_f.html) (at least in Haskell).

[Update] If you want to avoid the slice (that created a copy of the array):

```
[1, 2, 3].flat_map { |x| [x, :a] }.tap(&:pop)
#=> [1, :a, 2, :a, 3]
```

Comment: I wouldn't do `[0..-1]` in Haskell (and probably in Ruby too)

Comment: @VictorMoroz, what would you do instead?

Comment: @VictorMoroz: Added an inplace snippet. Ruby has no abstraction for this, so I've used tap+pop.

Answer (score 2):

Another similar solution uses `#product` :

```
[1, 2, 3].product([{}]).flatten(1)[0...-1]
# => [ 1, {}, 2, {}, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to zip another array of desired elements and then flatten it with `depth = 1`:

```
> arr = [1, [], "333"]
> element = {}
> interspersed = arr.zip([element] * (arr.size - 1)).flatten(1).compact
> # [1, {}, [], {}, "333" ]
```

You can extend `Array` to make this behavior more accessible.

```
class Array
  def intersperse(elem)
    self.zip([elem] * (self.size - 1)).flatten(1).compact
  end
end
```

e.g.,

> [43] pry(main)> [1,2,3].intersperse('a')
>   => [1, "a", 2, "a", 3]

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3]
h, *t = a
r = [h]
t.each do |e|
  r.push({}, e)
end
r #=> [1, {}, 2, {}, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
a = [1, [], "333"]
new_a = a.collect {|e| [e, {}]}.flatten(1)
=> [1, {}, [], {}, "333", {}]
```

You need to do `.flatten(1)` because it will flatten your blank array without it.

Or as @David Grayson says in the comment, you can do a `flat_map` which will do the same thing.

```
a.flat_map {|e| [e, {}]}
=> [1, {}, [], {}, "333", {}]
```

@tokland has the correct answer if the last {} is not necessary.  You return a slice from 0 to length - 1 or `[0..-1]`.

Comment: Shorter version:  `a.flat_map { |e| [e, {}] }`

Comment: Oh, nice!  And it doesn't flatten the blank array.  Good call.

Comment: only last `{}` was not required

Answer (score 1):

Another one that's similar to Tokland's:

```
xs.inject([]){|x,y| x << y << {}}[0...-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].inject { |memo, el| Array(memo) << {} << el }
#=> [1, {}, 2, {}, 3, {}, 4, {}, 5]
```

`inject` will use the first element to start with, so you don't need to mess with indices.

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):054:0* [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each_slice(1).flat_map {|e| e << "XXX"}[0...-1]
=> [1, "XXX", 2, "XXX", 3, "XXX", 4, "XXX", 5, "XXX", 6, "XXX", 7, "XXX", 8, "XXX", 9]
irb(main):055:0> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each_slice(2).flat_map {|e| e << "XXX"}[0...-1]
=> [1, 2, "XXX", 3, 4, "XXX", 5, 6, "XXX", 7, 8, "XXX", 9]
irb(main):056:0> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each_slice(3).flat_map {|e| e << "XXX"}[0...-1]
=> [1, 2, 3, "XXX", 4, 5, 6, "XXX", 7, 8, 9]
irb(main):057:0> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each_slice(4).flat_map {|e| e << "XXX"}[0...-1]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, "XXX", 5, 6, 7, 8, "XXX", 9]
irb(main):058:0> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each_slice(5).flat_map {|e| e << "XXX"}[0...-1]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "XXX", 6, 7, 8, 9]
irb(main):059:0> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each_slice(6).flat_map {|e| e << "XXX"}[0...-1]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "XXX", 7, 8, 9]
irb(main):060:0> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each_slice(7).flat_map {|e| e << "XXX"}[0...-1]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, "XXX", 8, 9]
irb(main):061:0> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each_slice(8).flat_map {|e| e << "XXX"}[0...-1]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, "XXX", 9]
irb(main):062:0> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each_slice(9).flat_map {|e| e << "XXX"}[0...-1]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
irb(main):063:0>
```