# How to get "string-like" join functionality for arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Consider the following input:

```
input = [:a, :b, :c]
# output = input.join_array(:x)
```

What is a readable and concise way to get the following output (in Ruby):

```
[:a, :x, :b, :x, :c]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert a new element in between all elements of a Ruby array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422258/how-to-insert-a-new-element-in-between-all-elements-of-a-ruby-array)

Comment: the name of the abstraction is "intersperse", you'll find some existing questions by that name.

Comment: Thanks, the name "intersperse" is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive approach:

```
input = [:a, :b, :c]

input.flat_map{|elem| [elem, :x]}[0...-1] # => [:a, :x, :b, :x, :c]
```

Without cutting last element:

```
res = input.reduce([]) do |memo, elem|
  memo << :x unless memo.empty?
  memo << elem
end

res # => [:a, :x, :b, :x, :c]
```

Comment: Upvoted, I think `.flat_map{|elem| [elem, :x]}[0...-1]` would be a little bit more readable though.

Comment: You can't use `[0..-1]`, it'll include trailing `:x`.

Comment: Notice the third dot `...` which makes the range exclusive

Comment: @BeatRichartz: ah! So you see, for some people it's just more confusing :)

Answer (score 2):

### Flatten a Product

You can use [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-product) to distribute :x throughout your array, and then flatten the result. For example:

```
input = [:a, :b, :c]
input.product([:x]).flatten
#=> [:a, :x, :b, :x, :c, :x]
```

### Trimming an Array

Assuming your desired result wasn't just a typo that accidentally excluded the last element, you can use [Array#pop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-pop), [Array#slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-slice), or other similar methods to trim the last element from the array. Some examples include:

```
input.product([:x]).flatten[0...-1]
#=> [:a, :x, :b, :x, :c]

output = input.product([:x]).flatten
output.pop
output
#=> [:a, :x, :b, :x, :c]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
input = [:a, :b, :c]
p input.zip([:x].cycle).flatten[0..-2] #=> [:a, :x, :b, :x, :c]
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, we could use `join`. Not necessarily readable or concise though!

```
[:a, :b, :c].join('x').chars.map(&:to_sym) # => [:a, :x, :b, :x, :c]

# Or, broken down:
input = [:a, :b, :c]
output = input.join('x')      # => "axbxc"
output = output.chars         # => ["a", "x", "b", "x", "c"]
output = output.map(&:to_sym) # => [:a, :x, :b, :x, :c]
```

Comment: It's not robust. Will break down on longer symbols :)

Answer (score 0):

How is this ?

```
input = [:a, :b, :c]
p input.each_with_object(:x).to_a.flatten[0..-2]
# >> [:a, :x, :b, :x, :c]
```